# Screen personal lock

Tags: android

How to bring up a constantly appearing screen in android, user should not be able to get rid of it unless he enters the correct password. None of the keypad,touch screen window should be enabled for user to get rid of this screen. I am trying to develop app for user security. 
Once User will starts this app. no one else can access his personal data. Thank you. any small hint , pointers are appreciated.

Comment: You are suggesting that a userland application be able to essentially brick a device. If a user wants to lock their device, they should be using Android's security features instead.

Comment: Yes, I want to do this.. do you have any resources.

Comment: I would think it obvious that being able to brick a device from a user application is undesirable behaviour, and even if you find a way to do it, it will likely be fixed in a later security update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to create your own, call locknow();

```
DevicePolicyManager mDPM;
mDPM = (DevicePolicyManager)getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
mDPM.lockNow();
```

There's a bunch of checking you need to do to gain this sort of access, and to make sure the device can be locked.  You'll also need to request the correct permission.

- [DevicePolicyManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html)
- [DeviceAdminSample.java](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/DeviceAdminSample.html)

Comment: Can you help me with some sample code to add permissions
thank you

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, I've not used it myself.  I'm guessing here, but I think the permission you'll need is BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN, but like I say, that's just guessed from browsing the docs.